# MyBatis-Spring multi-datasource configuration cache issues

Tags: spring, caching, transactions, mybatis

Using mybatis-3.1.0, spring-3.1.1.RELEASE, and mybatis-spring-1.1.0, we are facing some nasty cache issues in a multi-datasource configuration.

For security reasons, we have separate datasources pointing to the same database and schema, each datasource using different credentials. The goal is to use a db user having only select permissions for doing selects, another user with insert/update/delete permissions to do dml operations, and so on.

For doing so, we have configured three separate SqlSessionFactoryBeans, one for each datasource. And the problem comes here: when an insert operation is performed using the "DML" session, the local cache of "SELECT" sessions is not flushed. Therefore, for example, we do not see newly created users in the user list.

So my question is: do we have any way of configuring a single SqlSessionFactoryBean associated to all three datasources at the same time?

Update:

After some more debugging, it looks like the core issue is actually transaction management related. Some actions in the site involve several operations, and these operations are performed through different datasources. It looks like we are not correctly configuring the transaction manager, and one or more of those operations are left out of the commit. After several attempts, as the connections are exhausted, database operations get totally messed up.

So, the question now is, how to configure a single transaction manager to handle all involved datasources?

Comment: Have you tried by settng flushCache=true in your select statement?

Comment: setting flushCache to true will not help as this clear cache after executing select not before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one datasource can be associated with given sqlSessionFactory. But this is not the main problem. The main problem is that local cache is [associated](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/java-api.html#Local_Cache) with mybatis session. So when you use say two different sessions you will have two different local caches - one per session and having one sqlSessionFactory will not help.

The option you should probably consider is setting localCacheScope=STATEMENT for your read-only sessions. In this case it will not cache results after query executed. To be able to still use caching configure second level cache using custom adapter for some globally configured cache or [existing cache adapter](https://code.google.com/p/mybatis/wiki/Caches) which uses global cache e.g. ehcache.

Comment: You were right. Having a single session factory was not enough. It turned out to be related with mixing transactional and non-transactional operations within the same request. A test using a single datasource worked fine, and we finally managed to redefine the set of permissions so each operation requires a single session and transaction manager.